# AppController not found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can anyone tell what is wrong with my code.I am using cakephp 2.9.5.Getting error : Class 'app\Controller\AppController' not found

```
<?php
namespace app\Controller;
use app\Controller\AppController;

Class ProductsController extends AppController{

    public function index()
    {
        $prducts = $this->Product->find('all');

        print_r($prducts);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using the wrong namespace for the controller. Controllers in CakePHP have their own seperate namespaces.

Replace

```
namespace app\Controller;
use app\Controller\AppController;
```

With

```
use AppController;
```

or use this

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

This should work.

Comment: Neither of this will work. The proper namespace in CakePHP 3.x would be default be `App`, with an upperase `A`, and in CakePHP 2.x, importing requires to indicate the package (2nd argument of `App::uses()`, which isn't optional), in this case `Controller`.

Comment: @ndm Yes..I just missed that. Thanks I have edited the answer. But in cake 2.x `use AppController` will work fine.

Comment: I'd doubt that, It will most likely simply have no effect whatsoever, as not even when using composer there will be an autoloader that would able to load that reference (unless one would explicitly configure one). It will probably simply work because the `AppController` class/file has been already included from somewhere else.

Comment: Okay. I understand. I will have it tesed and update the answer. Thank you :)